# HR tag issue in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

What I am doing is using the `hr` as a separate table cell to split content.

Here is how it SHOULD look (no `hr` cell), **[JSFiddle Correct](http://jsfiddle.net/4Akrp/3/)** (only one section for example)

However, when I add my `hr` divider cell, it breaks everything. **[JSFiddle Incorrect](http://jsfiddle.net/4Akrp/2/)**

So the big picture is something like this..

```
<table>

<tr>
   //th's with content
</tr>

<tr><th class="col-xs-12"><hr class="square" /></th></tr>

<tr>
   //th's with content
</tr>

<tr><th class="col-xs-12"><hr class="square" /></th></tr>

</table>
```

Just need some help with correctly styling/css'ing the `hr` cells.

Comment: you should use `<th>` for table headers and `<td>` for table data (i.e. table cells)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/4Akrp/5/

I just added colspan="3"

```
<table>

<tr>
   //th's with content
</tr>

<tr><th class="col-xs-12" colspan="3"><hr class="square" /></th></tr>

<tr>
   //th's with content
</tr>

<tr><th class="col-xs-12" colspan="3"><hr class="square" /></th></tr>

</table>
```

Comment: I explained it in my answer.  Too bad you didn't see it :(

Answer (score 0):

On your last row (`<tr>`) you can add: `<tr><th class="col-xs-12" colspan="3"><hr class="square" /></th></tr>`

In Bootstrap, the `col-*` classes help you space within a container - in this case, a table header `<th>` (but it should be a table cell `<td>`).

What you want to do is expand the `hr` to take the width of the page (I am assuming) so you can either make the `<th>` span over several columns (as many as you have on the table), or you can simply put the `<hr>` tag outside the table (like right after your closing `</table>` tag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I asked and I received this
- you should prevent that put it outside the row or inside a column
-row has negative margin and i guess you don’t want the `hr` to stick out `15px` on each side.